# filter method with enums in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have a collection of persons, and each person has a name, age and country. Name is a string, age an int, and country an enum. I would like to make a filter method on this collection. It should be written in a way that I can easily add a new property in the future, for example e-mailaddresses, to the filter.

```
GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(string name, int age, Country country)
```

The problem with this method is that I would like to be able to also filter only by country and ignore name and age.

I could add the following methods:

```
GetAllPersonsFilteredByCountry(Country country)

GetAllPersonsFilteredByCountryAndName(Country country, String name)

GetAllPersonsFilteredByCountryAndAge(Country country, int Age)

GetAllPersonsFilteredByName(String Name)

and so on...
```

but then I would have duplicate code and a bunch of filter methods. 
Anoter option is to check for null. If null or an empty string is given for the name, then don't filter on name. The problem is you cannot give null as a parameter for an enum! So I always HAVE to give a country or int even I want to filter only on name and age and ignore country.

A third option would be a waterfall where I first filter on name, then on age, then on country based on a boolean:

```
GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(string name, bool filterName, int age, bool filterAge, Country country, bool filterCountry)
{
    List<Person> allPersons = getAllPersons();

    if (filterName)
        //filter all persons out the list based on the name parameter
          ...
    if (filterAge)
        //filter all persons out the list based on the age parameter
          ...
    if( filterCountry)
        //filter all persons out of the list based on the country parameter
          ...

    return allPersons;
}
```

This looks like the best solution, but I'm not sure. Maybe I can do something with optional and named parameters in c# to make a robust but flexible filtering method? Please do consider the face that enums cannot be null!

Comment: 1.) i dont see the enum 2.) try the language integrated query syntax? LinQ and Lambda Expressions you could search for

Comment: I say in the first line that Country is an enum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current solution requires a change in signature every time structure of Person change. It's not quite flexible and has lots of parameters, which makes it hard to read.

Try to pass a predicate, which will contain filtering information. In such a way you can define your own filters in calling code, while `GetAllPersonsFilteredBy` knows nothing about **how** filtering is made.

```
IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(Func<Person, bool> filter)
{
    List<Person> allPersons = getAllPersons();

    return allPersons.Where(filter);
}
```

now you can

```
var filteredPersons = GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(p => p.Name == "John" && p.Age < 60);
```

or even

```
var filteredPersons = GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(p => p.Name == "John" || p.Age < 60);
```

Note, that from the method call I can't even guess if the relation between parameters is `&&` or `||`. Also, you have more choice in specifying `p.Age < 60` or `p.Age == 60` or any other predicate

Comment: I ended up using this simple query syntax and it works smoothly, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can you not do:

```
GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(Country? country, string name = string.Empty, int age - 1)
```

The have a LINQ statement which is something like

```
// select statement
where ((country != null) ? MyCountry == country) &&
     ((name != string.Empty) ? MyName == name : true) &&
     ((age != -1) ? MyAge == age : true)
```

In this example it is assuming MyName and MyAge are the values, be it from the DB or wherever to check against

Answer (score 2):

Your last solution is closest to what I have seen most commonly, just wrap it up in a class:

```
class PersonFilter
{
    public string NameFilter { get; set; }

    public int? AgeFilter { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

etc.

Then you can use it in a way similar to this:

```
List<Person> GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(PersonFilter filter)
{
    IEnumerable<Person> result = getAllPersons();

    if (filter.NameFilter != null)
        result = result.Where(p => p.Name == filter.NameFilter);

    if (filter.Age.HasValue)
        result = result.Where(p => p.Age == filter.Age.Value);

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Further development would be to get rid of this bunch of `if`s of course. One of many possible solutions is to use the following utility method:

```
public static Expression<Func<Person, bool>> BuildFilter(IFilter filter)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p");

    List<Expression> conditions = new List<Expression>();
    foreach (var p in filter.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (p.GetValue(filter) != null)
        {
            Attribute filterAttribute
                = p.GetCustomAttributes(
                    typeof(FilterElementAttribute),
                    false).SingleOrDefault() as Attribute;

            if (filterAttribute == null)
            {
                continue; // throw internal error
            }

            var expressionType = ((FilterElementAttribute)filterAttribute)
                .ExpressionType;
            conditions.Add(
                Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType,
                                      Expression.Property(param, p.Name),
                                      Expression.Constant(p.GetValue(filter))));
        }
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(
        conditions.Aggregate((e1, e2) => Expression.And(e1, e2)),
        param);
}
```

With fields of the filter decorated in the following way:

```
public class FilterElementAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ExpressionType ExpressionType { get; private set; }

    public FilterElementAttribute(ExpressionType expressionType)
    {
        ExpressionType = expressionType;
    }
}

public class PersonFilter : IFilter
{
    [FilterElement(ExpressionType.Equal)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [FilterElement(ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual)]
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

`BuildFilter` method can be of course easily extended using generics to handle any entity/filter class.

Usage example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Person[] people = new[] 
        { 
            new Person() { Name = "p1", Age = 17 },
            new Person() { Name = "p2", Age = 18 } 
        };

    var onlyOver18 = BuildFilter(new PersonFilter() { Name = null, Age = 18 });
    Console.WriteLine(onlyOver18.ToString());

    foreach (var p in people.Where(onlyOver18.Compile()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: How would you get rid of the if's? I appreciate your suggestion because it is easy to understand and leans close to my way of thinking, but when I'm reviewing the other answers I think they offer more flexibility.

Comment: @user1884155 I've added one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nullable enum, this way you will be able to specify null. I'm assuming `Country` is the enum:

```
GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(string name, int age, Country? country)
{
     // ...

     if (Country.HasValue) {
         // filter here
     }

     // ...
}
```

The same goes for age, you can use a nullable int and make the method signature:

```
GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(string name, int? age, Country? country)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution I can suggest using a nullable type.
You can turn any enum or value type (such as int) to something that can also be null.
nullable type are defined with ? in the end. For example:

```
int? myNullable = null; // this is completely legal.
if(!myNullable.HasValue)
    muNullable = 3; // also completely legal.

// int realValue = myNullable; // this will throw a compilation error.
int realValue = myNullable.Value; // this is the right way to use the value
```

There's also this cute syntactic sugar:

```
int realValue = myNullable ?? 5; // if myNullable is null then 5, otherwise the value of myNullable
```

In your code:

```
GetAllPersonsFilteredBy(string name, bool filterName, int age, bool filterAge, Country? country, bool filterCountry)
{
    List<Person> allPersons = getAllPersons();

    if (filterName != null)
        //filter all persons out the list based on the name parameter
          ...
    if (filterAge != null)
        //filter all persons out the list based on the age parameter
          ...
    if(filterCountry.HasValue)
    {
        Country countryValue = filterCountry.Value;
        //filter all persons out of the list based on the country parameter
         ...
    }

return allPersons;
```

}

This simple solution will work, but I'd recommend going for a more sophisticated design using a composition of filters along these lines:

```
interface IFilter
{
    bool TestFilter(Person person);
}

class CompositeFilter : IFilter
{
    List<IFilter> _filters = new List<IFilter>();

    void AddFilter(IFilter filter)
    {
       _filters.Add(filter);
    }

    bool TestFilter(Person person)
    {
        foreach(IFilter filter in _filters)
        {
            if(!filter.TestFilter(person))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

class CountryFilter : IFilter
{
    Cuntry Country { get; set; }

    bool TestFilter(Person person)
    {
        return person.Country = this.Country;
    }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
CountryFilter countryFilter = new Countryfilter();
countryFilter.Country = Country.Jamaica;

filter.AddFilter(countryFilter);

if(filter.TestFilter(person))
{
 // pass
}
```